# Nameserver limits were exceeded while installing k3s

Tags: mysql, dns, k3s

I want to install Rancher in a Ubuntu server (v18.04). I am following this [doc](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/k8s-install/kubernetes-rke/) and I want to install k3s. When I install using the command

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh
```

everything works.

But when I try to install it using a MySQL database as the doc says:

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -s - server \
--datastore-endpoint="mysql://root:mypassword@tcp(localhost:3306)/dbk3s"
```

I received the following error:

```
Nameserver limits were exceeded, some nameservers have been omitted, the applied nameserver line is
```

MySQL server is running with no problem at all and I already created dbk3s database. It look likes the problem is related with the fact that Ubuntu is limited with just 3 DNS nameserver records and 6 DNS search records but I am not sure.